# Exact differences between Partner Community License and Enterprise Edition

Tags: limits, licenses, partner-communities

We are SI and ISV partners and I'm looking for an detailed feature comparison between regular Enterprise Edition Licenses and Partner Community Licenses. Best thing I found is this:

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_license_types_communities.htm&language=en_US

Is there more? In my experience the details (and their consequences) are very important. We found i. e. that the limitation "Read only" for Reports is a challenge, since there are not even the standard filters available (e.g. this year/last year). So to deliver appropriate reporting you need to create many similar redundant reports and easily end up in a maintenance trap for admins.

All the pricing seems to be non-public. Since there is a wide variety of bundles, it's not very clear to precisely drill down the available options for the client. In my experience not all of the AEs are very deep into this details - so a qualified partner support would be very helpful for joint sales. But the visible information seems very limited. Any ideas where to get more information?

Asking such questions at the support didn't end up very resourceful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are 3 links you may find more helpful than what you've already referenced Uwe.

I'm including the 1st one because you're an ISV.

[OEM User License Comparison](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/oem_user_license_comparison.htm).

[Getting Started With Communities](https://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_communities_implementation.pdf).

[Salesforce Communities Managers Guide](http://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_communities_managers_guide.pdf).

These seem to be the most comprehensive in terms of explaining the features available that can be enabled in communities by license type which I suspect is what you really want to know. Getting Started with Communities provides much more detail than anything else in terms of what a Partner user can do when it comes to reporting and dashboards.